# Помочь с кнопкой!

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте!

Есть кнопка для очистки корзины :

```
<p align="right" class="button-next" ><a href="cart.php?action=clear" >Очистить</a></p>
```

После нажатия на "Очистить" корзина очищается. Мне необходимо сделать так чтобы после нажатия меня не перебрасывало на страницу с корзиной, чтобы всплывало например модальное окно или какое-то уведомление и при этом корзина чистилась.

Comment: Использовать Ajax?

Comment: @entithat без понятия как...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам Ajax запрос в данном случае может выглядеть так (Ниже только пример с использованием JQuery):

```js
//Вешаем обработчик на ссылку
$(document).on("click","#cart_clear", function () {
    //Посылаем GET запрос на страницу/php-скрипт cart.php
    $.get("cart.php", {"action":"clear"}, function(callback) {
        //Тут добавляем код на показ модального окна или чего-то ещё
        //Необходимо только ещё проверить успешно ли отработал скрипт на стороне сервера.
    });

    //Запрещаем дальнейший переход на страницу
    return false;
});
```

```html
<!-- Присваиваем id ссылке, которая очищает корзину -->
<p align="right" class="button-next" ><a id="cart_clear" href="cart.php?action=clear" >Очистить</a></p>
```

Но тут ещё необходимо смотреть как обрабатываются данные в cart.php, так что простым копипастом обходится я не советую, а познакомиться с Ajax поближе.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! Подскажите, а как сделать так чтобы при нажатии чистилось и перенаправляло на указанную страницу?

Comment: JavaScript редирект реализуется при помощи document.location.href.
Например
document.location.href='http://www.example.com';

Comment: прошу прощения, а куда именно вставить это нужно?

Comment: В моём примере внутрь function(callback), после всех предварительных проверок

Comment: отлично, то что я хотел, большое спасибо! p.s загляни в мой 2 вопрос, может сможешь помочь... :)